# Oracle Forms automation using Cucumber or similar framework

Tags: automated-testing

I'm looking for toolset recommendations to automate testing of an Oracle Forms application, with the tests (ideally) to be driven from Cucumber.

I am aware of Oracle's [OATS](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/app-test/etest-101273.html). Can its APIs be called directly from another Java application, so I can avoid the whole record and playback idiom, or should I be looking somewhere else?

Thanks.

Comment: Really ... the sound of crickets ... no one automates against oracle forms using open source ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Oracle Test Manager does not have an API, so tests cannot be automatically generated or created that way. OpenScript, however, is a Java program at heart; like Rational Functional Tester, it appears to consist of some interesting Java libraries and a plugin bundled into Eclipse. Therefore, it is very likely you can use any Java-based framework with the OpenScript libraries to broaden your test capabilities.

This is what I have learned from poking at OATS and talking to a representative from Oracle, as our company is just starting to use it.

Answer (score 0):

OATS aka Open script doesn't support its API to call in another tool.

Oracle EBS forms automation best fits with OATS tool and is an Oracle tool.
It has whole bunch of features Functional testing, Load testing and Webservices . It has its own Test Management tool with reporting.
The tool is built on top of Eclipse IDE. You can integrate with other tool and jar libraries

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oem/app-test/index.html
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25294_01/doc.920/e15487/chap3_os_fm.htm